# Execute multiple custom WFFM Save Action

Tags: sitecore-client, wffm

I have two Save Action associated to my `WFFM`. One is custom which push data to some other application and second one is `WFFM's` `SendEmailMessage`.

Both are working perfectly, here I just want to trigger `SendEmailMessage` action post successful execution of first custom save action.

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what version do you use. 
For the versions before 8.2 there is present bug. And you would need to wrap actions that came out of the box with handling of submit state. It is described in [this article](https://www.exlrt.com/blog/handling-faulted-state-in-sitecore-wffm-save-actions).

For versions after 8.2 it should works fine. So, depending on what version you are, the easiest and less custom way could be upgrade WFFM.